# decimal number with ceil or floor in php

Tags: php

I have a result of decimal number

0.666667

and i wold like to fool it or round it to 0.6,

```html
number_format((float)0.66667, 1, '.', '')
```

but I get 0.7

```html
floor(0.66667)
```

gives me 0

how can i take this result and floor it to 0.6 or ceil it to 0.7

Comment: intval($num * 10) / 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply by 10, floor(), then divide by 10 again.

```
floor( 0.666667 * 10 ) / 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function floordec($zahl,$decimals=1){   
 return floor($zahl*pow(10,$decimals))/pow(10,$decimals);
}
echo floordec(0.66667);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.